# How do I add vertical errors bars (vertical lines) to a chart in Excel? The "vertical error bar" option is missing

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-365

I created a simple line chart in Excel 365, and I'm trying to add a vertical line to the chart at a specified date. I created the chart as a combo line chart (for the data) and a scatter plot with a single point on the important date. I planned to use vertical error bars on the scatter plot to create a vertical line, as I've done numerous times before. This time, though, **there is no option to add vertical error bars to the point. The only option is to add horizontal error bars.**

What's going on here? How do I add these vertical error bars? To add the error bars, I went to Chart Design --> Add Chart Element --> Error Bars --> More Error Bars Options.

### Screenshot 1: Chart and Data

[image: screenshot of chart and data]

### Screenshot 2: Chart Type Options

[image: chart options]

### Screenshot 3: Vertical Error Bars option is missing

[image: vertical error bars are missing in the menu]

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. Not able to replicate the issue. When I clicked on the point and added error bars, it first added horizonal only. But then I clicked on arrow to the right of the Error Bars window and selected "More Options".

[image]

Then it displayed a Vertical Error Bar window. Then back to the chart and I removed the horizontal error bars.